# dynamic grid style form that lets you update multiple rows in a single post in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm starting out with MVC but not sure it's the best option.

I need to create a form that is based upon a collection. Eg it might look like this:

product Price
Item 1 [textbox]
Item 2 [textbox]

[submit button]

where "item" is pulled from the database and textbox allows users to update the price.

essentially this is a type of datagrid but i don't want webforms style update each row one at a time i need to update the entire set of text boxes in one post.

Ideally I don't want a javascript based solution as it has to work without javascript.

Is this possible in MVC or should I stick to webforms (where I could do this in a repeater by iterating through he repeater items on postback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote blog entry about it: [ASP.NET MVC - Binding model to a list](http://caughtintoacameltrap.blogspot.com/2009/12/aspnet-binding-model-to-list.html)

To summarize:

For every row you have to generate inputs with proper prefixes. Sample:

```
<% foreach (var item in Model)
   { %>
<tr>
    <td>
        <%= Html.Hidden("contacts[" + i + "].ID", item.ID)%>
        <%= Html.TextBox("contacts[" + i + "].Name", item.Name)%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.TextBox("contacts[" + i + "].Surname",item.Surname)%>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%= Html.TextBox("contacts[" + i + "].Phone",item.Phone)%>
    </td>
</tr>
<%
    i++;
   } %>
```

And then in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult List(IEnumerable<Contact> contacts)
{
    //Here we have populated contact list, contacs parameter is filled with data from form. You save it here to your repository.
    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```